# Trying to get upstart to start and stop a nginx spawn-fcgi proccess

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, daemon, upstart

I am using spawn-fcgi to spawn a python app.  If I run below it works.

```
spawn-fcgi -d /home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbPixelServer/ -f /home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbPixelServer/index.py -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9001
```

Now I want to create a daemon so it cna start and stop and I can use monit to monitor the proccess.  I am a newbie upstart user but below is my file that I placed in /etc/init called pixelServer.conf.  I did a chmod +x on the file.

```
#!upstart
description "pixel server"
author      "Test"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
    export HOME="/root"

    echo $$ > /var/run/pixelServer.pid
    exec spawn-fcgi -d /home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbPixelServer/ -f /home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbPixelServer/index.py -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9001 >> /var/log/pixelServer.sys.log 2>&1

    #spawn-fcgi -d /home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbPixelServer/ -f /home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbPixelServer/index.py -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9001
end script

pre-start script
    # Date format same as (new Date()).toISOString() for consistency
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Starting" >> /var/log/pixelServer.sys.log
end script

pre-stop script
    rm /var/run/pixelServer.pid
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Stopping" >> /var/log/pixelServer.sys.log
end script
```

from the shell when I run the below, I get below error:

```
start pixelServer

start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.66" (uid=1000 pid=29176 comm="start pixelServer ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init"))
```

So...how to I fix the upstart file?  I know that spawn-fcgi does not like to be run as sudo.

Comment: I used the following "sudo start pixelServer" and I got it to work.  But when I do sudo stop pixelServer it does not kill the process.  Best practice for using upstart would be great.